# server window not seen in eclipse3.1

Tags: eclipse

I have just installed eclipse3.1 but server window not found in that.I have seen in windows >> show View >> Others but still not there .

Answer (score 1):

The server window is only visible with [**WTP**](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) installed, or with an eclipse distro like the [Java EE one](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

See this [comparison table](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages).

But I am unsure about the availability of such a feature is an old Eclipse distribution ([3.1, June 2005](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.1-200506271435/index.php))